# Ошибка: timed out waiting fro device dev-disk-by (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu

При запуске в режиме recovery mode
После запуска check all filesystem, появляется такое изображение. Из-за чего это может быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. [google: timed out waiting for device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401198/110559). 2. ну а вообще: изменился uuid блочного устройства (или оно вообще «пропало»).

Comment: А как это можно исправить?

Comment: А HDD вообще жив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это происходило, потому что в файле 
/etc/fstab

были прописаны строки с неверным UUID. 
То есть такого раздела уже нет на диске.